# make[1]: Nothing to be done for error problem

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

after make's Makefile did flawlessly and next it was renamed to Makefile_
then it's run by the exact command but being inserted with:

```
-f Makefile
```

so now

> make -f Makefile_  (... the rest identical),

then went out to give :

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'
```

How'd it mean and be solved ?

Comment: Everything is up to date, there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles are intelligent and only compile or recompile when necessary, for example if a change in the files has been detected.

So if you've altered your code and then ran your Makefile, it will compile the corresponding code. But if you run it again without changing anything, it will give you an error message saying that there isn't anything to be done.

Thus the message:

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'
```

If you want to avoid this, you can change a small part of your code just to recompile it or use the `-B` flag to force a remake.

With the `-B` flag, the command would be:

```
make -f Makefile_ -B
```